# adobe flex vbox enabled only works second time

Tags: apache-flex

I have a situation where I am using a data grid (flexicious), and when I select rows I want to enable/disable a pane below the grid.  If i have 1 row selected I want it enabled, if I have 0, or more than 1 selected I want it disabled.  The pane is intially disabled, and the enable works great 100% of the time.  `enabled="false"` only works after I have selected three rows.  If I have two rows selected I can prove I'm setting it to false, but it doesn't take.

I've tried `invalidateDisplayList`, firing an event to set `enabled="false"` a second time.  Nothing seems to work.

I am working in a Module if that makes any difference.  If I set `AlertInfoPanel.enabled=false`, it doesn't always work.

```
<mx:VBox>
<flexi:myGrid />
</mx:VBox>

<mx:VBox id="AlertInfoPanel" height="70%" width="100%" visible="{mAllowConfig}"  includeInLayout="{mAllowConfig}" enabled="false" >
     <mx:TabNavigator width="100%" height="100%" paddingTop="0" tabHeight="20" id="TAB_NAVIGATOR" >
                        <components:Tab1 label="{getToken('token_tab_general')}" id="generalInfoUI"/>
                        <components:Tab2 label="{getToken('token_tab_rules')}" />
     </mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I need to call `AlertInfoPanel.validateNow()`.

I don't understand why it works sometimes, but the `validateNow()` on the VBOX seems to work.

Comment: After spending a little more time playing with it, I believe one of the updates I was doing to the tab must have invalidated the tabNavigator, so I needed to call the validateNow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<mx:VBox id="AlertInfoPanel" height="70%" width="100%" visible="{mAllowConfig}" 
   includeInLayout="{mAllowConfig}" enabled="{myGrid.selectedItems.length==1}" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference.  I've tried it on the Tab Navigator even.

I do get a warning that it can't detect data binding on length, but it does appear to work the same as the programmatic calls.

Comment: We are in the dark ages, not using Spark yet.